# Convert unformatted JSON file to CSV

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to convert a JSON file into CSV. The issue is JSON file is not formatted uniformly.

```
{
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Lead",
                "url": "xyz"
            },
            "FirstName": "Bradford",
            "LastName": "Cosenza",
            "School_District__c": "Ross County",
            "Status": "Open",
            "CreatedDate": "2022-12-21T16:34:35.000+0000",
            "Email": "something@something.com",
            "Lead_ID__c": "00Q3b0000212gxh",
            "Id": "00Q3b0000212gxhEAA"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Lead",
                "url": "xyz"
            },
            "FirstName": "Bradford",
            "LastName": "Cosenza",
            "School_District__c": "Ross County",
            "Status": "Open",
            "CreatedDate": "2020-03-31T23:25:03.000+0000",
            "Verification_Status__c": "Invalid",
            "Verification_Date__c": "2022-08-05",
            "Email": "something@something.com",
            "Lead_ID__c": "00Q3b00001t0uNf",
            "Id": "00Q3b00001t0uNfEAI"
        },
```

Here is the snippet from the JSON file, but **Verification_Status__c,Verification_Date__c** is missing from the 2nd entry.

I used this code

```
import json
import csv

# Open the JSON file & load its data
with open('duplicate.json') as dat_file:
    data = json.load(dat_file)
stud_data = data['records']
 
# Opening a CSV file for writing in write mode
data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'w') 
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

count = 0 
for cnt in stud_data:
    if count == 0:
        header = cnt.keys()
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
        count += 1
    csv_writer.writerow(cnt.values())
data_file.close()
```

but I am getting scrambled data in CSV file

Comment: Please post the output and the desired output.

Comment: Use `csv.DictReader` and specify what to do with missing fields

Answer (score 0):

Can use a [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) if the records appear in different order or if the keys are missing from some records.

If there are nested objects in the JSON then they need to be flattened to export in the CSV output.

For the DictWriter, you will need the full set of keys when creating it, so can either create a fixed list at start or do two-passes over the data where the first pass will find the full set of keys and second pass creates the CSV file.

```python
import json
import csv

data = """{
"records":[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Lead",
            "url": "xyz"
        },
        "FirstName": "Bradford",
        "LastName": "Cosenza",
        "School_District__c": "Ross County",
        "Status": "Open",
        "CreatedDate": "2022-12-21T16:34:35.000+0000",
        "Email": "something@something.com",
        "Lead_ID__c": "00Q3b0000212gxh",
        "Id": "00Q3b0000212gxhEAA"
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Lead",
            "url": "xyz"
        },
        "FirstName": "Bradford",
        "LastName": "Cosenza",
        "School_District__c": "Ross County",
        "Status": "Open",
        "CreatedDate": "2020-03-31T23:25:03.000+0000",
        "Verification_Status__c": "Invalid",
        "Verification_Date__c": "2022-08-05",
        "Email": "something@something.com",
        "Lead_ID__c": "00Q3b00001t0uNf",
        "Id": "00Q3b00001t0uNfEAI"
    }
]}"""

# full set of keys in JSON for the CSV columns
keys = ["Id",
        "FirstName",
        "LastName",
        "School_District__c",
        "Status",
        "CreatedDate",
        "Verification_Status__c",
        "Verification_Date__c",
        "Email",
        "Lead_ID__c",
        "type",
        "url"
        ]
```

Next convert data to list of dictionary objects
and write output to CSV file.

```python
# Open the JSON file & load its data
# use json.loads() to load from string or json.load() to load from file
data = json.loads(data)
stud_data = data['records']

# Opening a CSV file for writing in write mode
with open('data_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as data_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(data_file, fieldnames=keys)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for row in stud_data:
        # flatten the sub-elements in attributes object
        attrs = row.pop("attributes", None)
        if attrs:
            for k,v in attrs.items():
                row[k] = v
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

**Output:**

```
Id,FirstName,LastName,School_District__c,Status,CreatedDate,Verification_Status__c,Verification_Date__c,Email,Lead_ID__c,type,url
00Q3b0000212gxhEAA,Bradford,Cosenza,Ross County,Open,2022-12-21T16:34:35.000+0000,,,something@something.com,00Q3b0000212gxh,Lead,xyz
00Q3b00001t0uNfEAI,Bradford,Cosenza,Ross County,Open,2020-03-31T23:25:03.000+0000,Invalid,2022-08-05,something@something.com,00Q3b00001t0uNf,Lead,xyz
```